# Connecting LAN cable to wall socket

Tags: networking, internet, lan, connection, cable

I have a few computers I want to connect to internet.

All PCs are connected to a network switch. My task is to connect the switch to the internet router. The cable that came from the internet router has 6 wires (I have no control over this). This cable has to be connected to socket as shown in the picture. The green cable (with 8 wires) is the cable that comes from my network switch to the socket.

[image]

In which order should I connect the 6 wire cable to the socket so that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

If it has 6 wires it means the router has a 100MB/Sec speed. You'll only need 8 wires (4 Pairs) for a gigabyte connection.
A 100MB connection uses only orange and green.

On your socket there is a picture, a table with multiple colors. You connect it as it is displayed. You'll have two pictures: TIA-A and TIA-B standard. Follow TIA-B and leave out the brown pair.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it looks like your green patch cable is using T-568B standard. Just follow the diagrams on your keystone, you can see the upper is listed A and lower - B. Follow the B and wire accordingly, the half squares indicate striped wire and the solid square indicates single colour wires.